# Как защитить клиентские устройства WiFi от Key Reinstallation Attacks?

Tags: android, безопасность, wifi

Недавно была [опубликована](https://habrahabr.ru/company/pentestit/blog/340182/) информация о ряде критических уязвимостей протокола WPA2, который повсеместно используется в сетях WiFi. Насколько я понял, обновления прошивки со стороны WiFi точки недостаточно и необходимо закрывать уязвимость на клиентах.

В связи с этим возникает вопрос, что делать с устройствами на базе Android, поддержка которых со стороны производителя прекращена (или ее вообще не было) и тех, для которых еще не были выпущены официальные патчи? Какие есть способы обнаружить/не допустить атаку и предотвратить кражу данных?

Comment: вы хотите решить проблему для конкретного случая, или как-то автоматизировать ПО, которая решает проблему? я думаю пропатчат протокол и всё, временно используйте другой

Comment: Я хочу что-то вроде перечня рекомендаций, которые на уязвимых устройствах помогут снизить риск данной атаки к минимуму. Но я совершенно не разбираюсь в сути данного вопроса и в механизмах упомянутой уязвимости.Я хочу понять, что я как простой пользователь могу сделать, чтобы обезопасить себя, при условии, что пользоваться WiFi я перестать не могу.